# Unable to Connect To Repo Server On Local Network

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, redhat, package-management, repository

I currently have two VMs:

- **node1** (192.168.55.201)
- **repos** (192.168.55.203)

I'm trying to set up **node1** so that it can retrieve packages from the repo server. I currently have the AppStream repo, and httpd set up on the **repos** host.

```
[root@rhel9 test_repos]# tree -d AppStream/
AppStream/
├── Packages
└── repodata


[root@rhel9 test_repos]# systemctl status httpd
● httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2023-09-13 11:51:53 UTC; 18min ago
       Docs: man:httpd.service(8)
   Main PID: 37453 (httpd)
     Status: "Total requests: 20; Idle/Busy workers 100/0;Requests/sec: 0.0182; Bytes served/sec:  10 B/sec"
      Tasks: 213 (limit: 11077)
     Memory: 23.1M
        CPU: 1.929s
     CGroup: /system.slice/httpd.service
             ├─37453 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
             ├─37454 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
             ├─37455 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
             ├─37456 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
             └─37457 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND

Sep 13 11:51:53 rhel9.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Sep 13 11:51:53 rhel9.localdomain systemd[1]: Started The Apache HTTP Server.
Sep 13 11:51:53 rhel9.localdomain httpd[37453]: Server configured, listening on: port 80
```

On **node1** ,I created the AppStream.repo file in `/etc/yum.repos.d`

```
[AppStream]
name=AppStream
baseurl=http://192.168.55.203:/test_repos/AppStream
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1
```

When I attempt to run a `dnf update`, I get the following error:

```
Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'AppStream':
  - Status code: 404 for http://192.168.55.203/test_repos/repodata/repomd.xml (IP: 192.168.55.203)
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'AppStream': Cannot download repomd.xml: Cannot download repodata/repomd.xml: All mirrors were tried
```

When I check the repo data directory on the **repos** host, I can see the `repodata.xml` file does exist.

```
└── repodata
    ├── 278a30984eda05dd66bf5b64b4c73e3ad594b4d7e53c88a2c65aeaa0c5948590-filelists.xml.gz
    ├── 538c923c865cbbe37031914cb741d828109b4ca5a75d7295a44044a5919d5dfa-primary.sqlite.bz2
    ├── 58ab9375821de1a81796ad3f0037d2dfa2ab8b1659ed191152ac848a7851c7d8-filelists.sqlite.bz2
    ├── a5bca624b05d997d2558ed577fe5eceba8429ef7df1237d95f5dd3d57c5e8165-other.xml.gz
    ├── b77637ccd437dfab4e6352a43838094f7d9c6a4c91de7ccb97e11ca83b349fed-primary.xml.gz
    ├── ecb122d15f31549a564c15d66fb89e336e777812ae30c83620fa53f6df86f4b5-other.sqlite.bz2
    ├── productid
    └── repomd.xml
```

I completed the following troubleshooting:

- Successfully pinged **repos** from **node1** and vise versa
- Successfully curld **repos** from **node1** and got the apache welcome page
- Ensured that firewall rules were set up on **repos**

```
public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: eth0 eth1
  sources:
  services: cockpit dhcpv6-client http ssh
```

Any idea what the issue could be?

Thanks !

Comment: Where did you store the repo files? Did you permit apache to have rights to access these files and directories? Did you check the error logs of apache?

Comment: @RomeoNinov Thanks for answering. After checking the error logs, I could see Permission Denied. The issue was that I didn't have the correct file context on my test_repos directory. It should have been `httpd_sys_content_t` Issue is now solved. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

After checking the error logs, I could see Permission Denied message. The issue was that I didn't have the correct file context on my `test_repos` directory. It should have been `httpd_sys_content_t` Issue is now solved.